# Allow user to enter username before mounting shared drive

Tags: command-line, networking, mount, gnome-terminal, cifs

I have a mount drive which I usually mount using

`sudo cifs -o "username=myshareddrive_username,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)" //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu`

Now, I have some linux machines which are accessible by some users. On each machine there is only one user account for all users to use to login to the machine. I wonder how I can allow the users to mount the shared drive using their shared-drive network credentials without having to open terminal and running a command as some of them are not very good in technical things? noting that each user has his unique network credentials (username and password) on the shared drive.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen The problem I'm not talking about machine users credentials, I'm talking about network shared drive credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
sudo cifs -o "username=$(>&2 echo -n "Enter remote username: "; read u; echo $u),uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)" //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu
```

---

**Explanation:**

```
$(>&2 echo -n "Enter remote username: "; read u; echo $u)
```

This will open a subshell and add its output (`stdout`) to your command.
It's basically equivalent to `$(id -u)`, just that you use `read` to ask for user input. The nested subshell will always be executed first.
The line `Enter remote username:` needs to be send to `stderr` (`>&2`) for that it is not part of the output that is added to your command.

Comment: You are awesome!!!

Comment: You know how I can run it using a desktop shortcut?

Comment: can use `pkexec` and `zenity` instead of `sudo` and `read`. Try something like this: `pkexec cifs -o "username=$(zenity --entry --text "Enter remote username"),uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)" //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu`

Comment: You mean place this `pkexec cifs -o "username=$(zenity --entry --text "Enter remote username"),uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)" //server-address/folder /mount/path/on/ubuntu` in the `exec` of the desktop entry?

Comment: or put it in a shell script that you execute from the desktop file. Something like this. But this is a new question, and I'm sure you will find many similar questions regarding how to execute a script from gui on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define the share in /etc/fstab with user option but without username and uid? In that case any user can mount a drive and it will ask for credentials.

With GUI there might be some differences. I tried it in Ubuntu Mate. If share is not defined in /etc/fstab I can use filemanager to navigate to server, it shows me shares and when I click on the share it asks for username and password